# Get daily data for Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, model, phpmyadmin

I want to get daily data from my database. I try 2 code and both are not working for me.

```
$sales=Sale::whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today());
```

The error that I got:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Carbon' not found

and when I try

```
$sales=Sale::whereDay('created_at', now()->day)->get();
```

The error that I got:

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\now()

Comment: what version of laravel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put  `use Carbon\Carbon;` at top after `namespace` then use this code.

```
$sales=Sale::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();
```

Comment: Happy to help. Happy coding,

Answer (score 1):

You should try to import Carbon and then use it:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Then inside your code you can use Carbon like:

```
Carbon::now();

Carbon::today();
```

Answer (score 1):

here in laravel created_at returns a value with Y-m-d & time & minute with all of this information

$now=Carbon::now();
here how returns the value  with Y-m-d & time & minute with all of this information.&it changing every second.

Now here if you want to get your query then need to format your getting now or today.try this,

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

```
$now_date=Carbon::today()->fomat('Y-m-d');
$sales=Sale::whereDate('created_at', '=',$now_date);
```

Comment: if this solution solve your problem then you can select my answer